# Do these blood pressure readings make sense?

Tags: blood-pressure

One day, I went to many pharmacists to measure my blood pressure. I found that the readings are different. I don't know wither my blood pressure rapidly changes or the devices are not very accurate. I tried analog and digital devices.

Now, I don't know the actual blood pressure reading and I don't know wither it is high or normal.

Here is my readings in one day:

**Morning:**

160/97

**Night:**

150/100

After 5 min of walking in a street: 130/80

After 5 min of walking in a street: 120/90

After 5 min of walking in a street: 125/85

Does that make sense?

Thank you very much,

Comment: This seems like a personal medical question. Questions requesting personal medical advice are off-topic here. To avoid closure, please try to edit the question so that it is generic. Personal questions should be taken to your personal physician who can examine you and access your full medical records. For more information, please see this [meta post](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/56/are-personal-medical-advice-questions-on-topic-here/258).

Comment: I don't think it's a request for medical advice since the actual question is simply if the numbers make sense. The trouble is, it's unclear what you mean by "makes sense." Makes sense how? The numbers are all valid BP readings. Are you asking if the drop in pressure following a walk is unexpected? Or are you questioning the accuracy of the devices?